# DataGridview gives null values in its columns even after manually populating them

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, null

I have used DataGridview, which is supposed to be populated manually (No data sources specified). I want to get its content of first row(index-0). But it gives me null cell values.

**Code**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr;

dt.Columns.Add("Description");
dt.Columns.Add("Unit Price");
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
dt.Columns.Add("Tot");

dr = dt.NewRow();

dr[0] = dataGridViewA_General.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value; //these values are null
dr[1] = dataGridViewA_General.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value; //these values are null
dr[2] = dataGridViewA_General.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value; //these values are null
dr[3] = dataGridViewA_General.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value; //these values are null

dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Thanks in advance

**Updated**

```
// dataGridViewA_General

this.dataGridViewA_General.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode =         System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.dataGridViewA_General.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
this.Column_A_item_code,
this.Column_A_description,
this.Column_A_qntity,
this.Column_A_unit_price,
this.Column_A_list_total});

// Column_A_description

this.Column_A_description.AutoSizeMode =  System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
this.Column_A_description.HeaderText = "Description";
this.Column_A_description.Name = "Column_A_description";

// Instantiate
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridViewA_General;
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column_A_description;
```

(rest of the columns are also defined in the sameway.)

Comment: Can you please post your gridview declaration on your aspx page?

Comment: @MaxDataSol I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise it was winforms

Answer (score 3):

You must add the row to the DataTable.

```
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

NewRow(); simply creates a blank row, you must add it manually.

Also, as you didn't put anything in the row itself, nothing will be returned.

Comment: I have done it in my code already. Actually matter is it does not fills those DataRows but gives null values.

Thanks for the reply

Comment: this code get executed only after adding values into the datagridview-manually in GUI. Thus rows can't be null but they are null :(

Answer (score 0):

I had done done a logical mistake and code had not been executed in expected manner after filling data. Actually the above code is correct. Thank you all for your valuable contribution.